# jQuery list item Menu

Tags: jquery, menu, traversal

We have a main menu, that could consist of any number or parent child items. We want all children ULs hidden to start with, then on click of a given li it's child UL shows.

You can see this working to a degree here: http://jsfiddle.net/JnL58/12/

```
$("ul.nav_categories ul").hide();

$("ul.nav_categories li").click(function(el){
    el.preventDefault();
    var cur_el = $("> ul", this);
    if (cur_el.length > 0) {
        $("> ul", this).show();
    }
});
```

The thing we are struggling with is hiding the relevant UL's APART from the clicked elements parent UL's or sibling Ul's.

So essentially its a drop down menu like this http://jsfiddle.net/FjCcT/4/ that works on click rather than rollovers :

```
$("ul.nav_categories ul").hide();
$("ul.nav_categories li").hover(function(){
    if ($("> ul", this).length > 0) {
        $("> ul", this).show();
    }
}, function(){
    if ($("> ul", this).length > 0) {
        $("> ul", this).hide();
    }
});
```

Please note this need to work on varying levels, eg 2, 3, 4 and possibly 5 items deep. The lists are dynamic so we will not know the number of levels.

Comment: What's not working in the first fiddle ?

Comment: `$("ul.nav_categories ul").hide();` should be replaced by `ul.nav_categories ul{display:none;}` in CSS.

Comment: adeneo - in the first fiddle, we need to hide ul's when another li is clicked, so we only show one path through the lists at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total edit. Of course the solution has to be super simple. :3

```
$("ul.nav_categories ul").hide();

$("ul.nav_categories li").click(function(){
    $('li > ul').not($(this).parents('ul')).hide();
    $(this).find('> ul').show();
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bhnzc/3/

Comment: the nested menus don't open on click in your jsfiddle

Comment: This almost works - though I think clicking on "Sub page A (has children)" a 2nd time should close that node. :?

Comment: Hi Kaloyan, this is almost there, thank you. As Nathan pointed out this need to work for varying depths, if we add another level it no longer works... see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhnzc/2/